# Dynamic image height in tableview with using sdwebimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, tableview

I want dynamic height image show in tableview, image is come from url so I am using the sdwebimage.
Sdwebimage set image in background thread.

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: encodedurl1]  completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
  }];
```

I am update the constraint height of image view in this thread.

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: encodedurl1]  completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
     CGFloat multiplier = (CGRectGetWidth(self.imageView.bounds) / image.size.width);
    [self.imageViewHeightConstraint setConstant:multiplier * image.size.height];
 }];
```

This code is helpful for me but I get image size in background thread
So, I take a time to update the height of constraint image view

I am search and goggling last 2 days.
This type issue get many developer, but not answer in any question in stack overflow.

Comment: Try to reload indexpath while image downloaded. and give top,bottom,leading,trailing constraints to imageview and greater than equal height constraint to imageview. and also add  this in viewDidLoad : tblViewDetail.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 ;
    tblViewDetail.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: try to pass estimatedRowHeight for tableView only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Helper method which created for my project.

```
-(void)imageWithURL:(NSURL *)imageurl WithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath WithCallback:(void(^)(UIImage *downloadedImage,BOOL isCache , NSIndexPath *imageIndexPath))callback{
    if (![[SDWebImageManager sharedManager ]diskImageExistsForURL:imageurl]) {
        [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager]downloadImageWithURL:imageurl options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
            // resize image here
            callback(image , NO,indexpath);
        }];

    }
    else{
        UIImage *image = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:[imageurl absoluteString]] ;
        // resize image here
        callback(image, YES ,indexpath);
    }

}
```

**Call this method in cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                    [self imageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objPreparations.strImageURL] WithIndexPath:indexPath WithCallback:^(UIImage *downloadedImage, BOOL isCache, NSIndexPath *imageIndexPath) {

                        if (downloadedImage) {
                            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                UITableViewCell  *existcell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:imageIndexPath];
                                if (existcell) {
                                    // assign image to cell here
                                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[imageIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }];
                });
```

**Dont Forgot**

In viewDidLoad

```
tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 ;
 tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

And also Give top,bottom,leading,trailing constraints to imageview and greater than equal height constraint to imageview

Comment: This is take a much time for load cell because reload at row.
I have a many row in table, my app has many image like fb.

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: because this method check that image already downloaded then it will comes with that images . but if you are run with your method then it will download image everytimes.

Comment: I might have already forgotten ObjC but it looks like whatever version of SDWebImage you used has `diskImageExistsForURL` as sync whereas in the SDWebImage I have there is only an async version. Feels like I'm out of luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

do the update in main thread like

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: encodedurl1]  completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         CGFloat multiplier = (CGRectGetWidth(self.imageView.bounds) / image.size.width);
         [self.imageViewHeightConstraint setConstant:multiplier * image.size.height];
         [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
     });
 }];
```

Comment: In main thread, not update the height of image constraint, because update height before load image.

Comment: try adding `[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`, updated the answer.